# adding shadow without calling CGContextFillPath(context);

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 1.5), 
                       2.0, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
```

and to apply the shadow based on my understanding I'd have to call CGContextFillPath. Is there other way to do this without calling fill path?

Comment: Apply the shadow to what? If there's nothing to be drawn, how should it figure out which shape the shadow has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You have to draw something in the graphics context using a stroke or path method to generate a shadow. Here is the documentation from Apple.

> How Shadows Work
>
> Shadows in Quartz are part of the graphics state. You call the
>   function CGContextSetShadow, passing a graphics context, offset
>   values, and a blur value. After shadowing is set, any object you draw
>   has a shadow drawn with a black color that has a 1/3 alpha value in
>   the device RGB color space. In other words, the shadow is drawn using
>   RGBA values set to {0, 0, 0, 1.0/3.0}.
>
> You can draw colored shadows by calling the function
>   CGContextSetShadowWithColor, passing a graphics context, offset
>   values, a blur value, and a CGColor object. The values to supply for
>   the color depend on the color space you want to draw in.
>
> If you save the graphics state before you call CGContextSetShadow or
>   CGContextSetShadowWithColor, you can turn off shadowing by restoring
>   the graphics state. You also disable shadows by setting the shadow
>   color to NULL.